# Prevent fill from copying controls?

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel spreadsheet with many checkboxes linked to cells in the sheet between the checkboxes.

Then I have formatting based on the condition of the check-boxes and some other data.

Now I need to change the formats or formulas so I change some cells and then fill to change the rest.

The problem is that fill copies the checkboxes along all the ranges such that the first checkbox then appears in all the cells. (Copy and paste does work without the checkboxes but that becomes difficult as the clipboard is constantly reset by this or other spreadsheets.)

Is there any way to stop this behavior and leave the all the checkboxes where they are when filling. So far none of the fill options are working.

An alternate solution that would work for me,

The checkboxes were all created using a vba macro which put them in a cell and linked the correct cell in the sheet.
I can easily re-create the checkboxes if I can first remove them.

I know of `CheckBoxes.Delete` but I cannot use it on the sheet as there are other checkboxes in the sheet that I cannot remove.
Is there a way to remove all checkboxes only in a specific range?

This would allow me to format as needed, remove all the checkboxes and re-create them.

Comment: are the checkboxes form controls or activex controls?

Comment: I believe they the are form controls. 'As CheckBox' in VBA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is for your alternate solution.   If you are creating these on the fly then give them a name to distinguish them from the rest.  Then you can loop through each, check the name and delete

```
Sub RemoveCheckBoxes()
Dim checkBoxKeyWord As String
'Lets say this is what each checkbax name starts with
checkBoxKeyWord = "cbRemovable"

Dim shp As Shape
'loop through the sheet and check the shapes (Form controls are shapes)
For Each shp In Sheets(1).Shapes
    'see if the name matches
    If Left(shp.Name, Len(checkBoxKeyWord)) = checkBoxKeyWord Then
        'delete the checkbox
        shp.Delete
    End If

Next

End Sub
```

Here is a version that checks the range

```
Sub RemoveCheckBoxes()
Dim checkBoxKeyWord As String
Dim r As Range
Set r = Sheets(1).Columns("B")
'Lets say this is what each checkbax name starts with
checkBoxKeyWord = "cbRemovable"

Dim shp As Shape
'loop through the sheet and check the shapes (Form controls are shapes)
For Each shp In Sheets(1).Shapes
    'see if the name matches
    If Left(shp.Name, Len(checkBoxKeyWord)) = checkBoxKeyWord Then
        Dim cbRange As Range
        Set cbRange = Sheets(1).Range(shp.ControlFormat.LinkedCell)
        If Not Application.Intersect(cbRange, r) Is Nothing Then
            'delete the checkbox as its linked cell is in the range
            shp.Delete
        End If
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks that is brilliant. However, it will only work for future checkboxes. I still have to delete all the extra checkboxes I have already created. I am trying to look up the LinkedCell property and see if it is in the range. Otherwise simply stepping though your code is still way faster than deleting manually.